# How do I Return my View and call a btn function on it's form?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Controller `myCustomers` with a View.

The controller has two useful ActionResults; namely `loadDataTotbl` and `CreatePDF`.

```
(Filestream with Itextsharp).
```

`loadDataTotbl` loads the View fine which is simply a db obj via LINQ.

The View has a table in a form with some elements and a create PDF button e.g.:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("CreatePDF", "myCustomers", FormMethod.Post))
   {
     <form>
        <table>
           @foreach (var cn in Model)
           {
              <input type="text" value="@pn.CustomerName" name="cNameVal" />
            }
            <input type="submit" value="Download the PDF" />
         </table>
     </form>

    }
```

It works fine. When I hit the button, PDF gets created.

How do I create the PDF but hide/bypass this view? Please note my View has to remain as I strip it's headers and values and use them in CreatePDF action to create and design my PDF.

Do I need partial view? How would it work here?

I don't think I can hide views if they have data I need.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please share your controller code that generates/create pdf file.

Comment: Thanks Yogi. I managed to do it just now actually by calling the CreatePDF Action in my loadDataTotbl Action like so:

Comment: Public ActionResult loadDataTotbl() { //do data loading code return CreatePDF(); } and even though my data was loaded into the CreatePDF Action like so: string cNameVal = Request.Form["cNameVal"]; you can see no form data was passed to the CreatePDF call from within loadDataTotbl and because I am passing nothing form data did not make it into the PDF. So as an addon query how do I pass the RequestForm values to CreatePDF so that data does go into the PDF once it's generated?

Comment: TO ADD: The PDF function is defined as so: [HttpPost]
        public FileStreamResult CreatePDF(){}